# query rdf file windows

Tags: python, windows, rdf

I wanna know how to query a RDF file using Sparql on windows. I'm using python 2.7 and on linux os.system(roqet... ) is there something similar to roqet (rasqal) on windows, like curl for example?, can I make this query with rdflib or something like that? it is very important that this rdf is not online, I wanna perform this query locally through the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at either the [ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/cmds.html) tools provided by [Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org) which will run on Windows provided Java is installed

Or take a look at the [rdfQuery](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=rdfQuery) tool provided by [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) which will run on Windows provided .Net 4.0 Full is installed

*Disclaimer* - I'm a developer on both of the above projects

Comment: In fact I recommend jena arq, I just made it work... I was thinking about dotNetRDF but when I install .net Framework 4.0 windows still complains me not having it installed even though I actually have it, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: You need .Net Framework 4.0 *Full* rather than the standard *Client Profile* install for dotNetRDF (at least for the Toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is reasonably small (less than a few 100,000 triples), I would highly recommend [RDFlib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib), as you suggested.  It can be used anywhere you've installed Python and allows full use of SPARQL (both select and update/delete statements), and also gives many other handy features that can be utilized on a local file completely in-memory.

The nice part about using RDFlib is that to get it up and running requires only adding the Python library, so it is very simple to install.